# Magento 2: Does a user created cart interfere with a REST created cart or continue?

Tags: magento2, cart, rest-api, integration

The question I have, If a customer has created a cart via a website.
And then for customer service reasons, the customer calls in a want to place an order, By using the API's (let's say Salesforce or some other integration), does that cart interfere?

Does it pick up that same cart, or create a new cart.

Comment: Yes, He will get the same cart.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

- When you pass customer token - Magento API refers the Quote ID of
  that customer.
- You can fetch those data using this API.

---

```
GET    /V1/carts/mine/items
```